# How do I declare function in C, so that GCC will compile its code without using x86 call convention?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, x86

I'm talking about the first two asm instructions that appear in the beginning of each function that GCC compiles:

```
push %rbp
mov %rsp, %rbp
```

Later on, I need that function address to be passed somewhere else, so I need the exact thing that GCC does with every function code, except the two above instructions omitted , and that the binary code will begin straight with the code of my function. So no workarounds like making it inline will help me. How do I do this?

P.S. I can of course pass the function address with the addition of some value to skip these two instructions, but I want more elegant solution.

Comment: Make the function inline ?

Comment: But I need that function address to be passed somewhere else

Comment: Add `-fomit-frame-pointer` to gcc command line

Comment: @user1483597: it would probably be a good idea to mention important constraints such as this *in the question*, no ?

Comment: I'm a little curious what the end goal is here.  This might be an [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem). Also keep in mind that your workaround of adding some value to the function address to skip over the prologue probably won't work (depending on what you're trying to do) since the return point(s) in the function will try to undo what the prologue did, and may screw up the stack and/or some registers in the process.